# Embed seaborn plots in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, seaborn

I'm trying to embed plots from `seaborn` into `tkinter` gui for **iris dataset**. It works all fine when i save the image and reuse it but it is not an effective solution,Is there any alternate way to dynamically do the same without saving `img` in local filesystem

Here is the code

```
import tkinter as tk
import seaborn as sns

class Application(object):
    def __init__(self,parent,**kwargs):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.geometry("900x600")
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.vis_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.parent)
        self.vis_frame.grid(column=1,row=5,sticky='WE')
        self.gui_button()

    def gui_button(self):
        df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
        columns = df.columns


        for i in range(len(columns)):
                    button = tk.Button(self.vis_frame,text=columns[i],command = lambda c=columns[i]: self.gui_plot(df,c))
                    button.grid(row=i+1,column=0,sticky='W')

    def gui_plot(self,data,column):
        from PIL import ImageTk, Image
        self.sns_plot = sns.pairplot(data,hue=column,size=1.5)
        self.sns_plot.savefig('plot.png')
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('plot.png'))
        self.vis = tk.Label(self.vis_frame,image=img)
        self.vis.image = img
        self.vis.grid(row=0,column=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to say in which way it does not "work all fine" with this code.

Comment: @mwaskom In this case it works fine as i'm saving the figure bcoz it is 'pairplot'. suppose i use 'distplot', Seaborn doesn't give an option to save the figure(sns_plot.savefig) . in which case i can't bring it to GUI.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the work around solution. seaborn pairplot does not have ikinter/canvas interface, such as, figure or axes. This solution save into image and then read from image can be the solution for now. Other seabron plots: scatterplot (relational plot), heatmap, histplot (histogram plot), categorical plot. They all can be integrate into tkinter with ax parameters.